# Update a div section in html every x seconds

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to get a part of the html code to update every x seconds as follows:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
   $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here" );
  }, 3000);
 });
</script>

<div id="here">[get_email]</div>
```

Where [get_email] is a shortcode:

```
function mm_get_current_user_email(){
 global $current_user;
 get_currentuserinfo();

 $email = $current_user->user_email; 

 return $email;
} 
add_shortcode( 'get_email', 'mm_get_current_user_email');
```

The problem is that the value is not updated every x seconds (set to 3 seconds here), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/ the second argument must be a `callable`, you're passing a `string`. Try to remove the quotes `'`.

Comment: @majusebetter That's not JS, you can't just pass not quoted PHP function name. Check examples at the bottom of page.

Comment: @aser23 Do you see requests in network tab? Try changing selector to `load(url + ' #here > *')`. Also in shortcode function just do `return date('H:i:s');` to see if content actually changes

Comment: @Justinas Yes, maybe that's not the problem here, but there is something like "First Class Callable Syntax": https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.first_class_callable_syntax.php

Comment: @majusebetter Yes, please read that. `add_shortcode('get_email', mm_get_current_user_email);` is syntax error

Comment: @Justinas Yes, I already got your point. See my comment above. I just wanted to point you to the fact that PHP has something like first-class functions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change load and also add_shortcode but it is not working